# Modifying “pg_hba.conf” file to listen a dynamic address

Tags: postgis, postgresql

this is the sequel of ["Modifying "pg_hba.conf" file to listen local TCP/IP conection"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122696/modifying-pg-hba-conf-file-to-listen-local-tcp-ip-conection)

I manage to modify pg_hba.conf to listen other PCs and allow them through the firewall, but my problem now is that the addresses are dynamic, so the configuration work for one day, but in the next day the router assigns the addresses randomly and we are in trouble again. When I use mySQL I use to work it around using the machine name as the server, but if I use it in the pg_hba it doesn't work. I show you:

what works:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             192.168.1.18/32         md5
```

what doesn't:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             the_mch_name/32         md5
```

Is there any solution besides static IP?

Comment: This question does note relate to any GIS topic as it is about generic configuration of PostgreSQL and not specific to PostGIS. You might want to ask your question over at [Database Administrators SE](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278379/how-to-configure-postgresql-to-accept-all-incoming-connections see answer( all 0.0.0.0/0 md5)

Comment: I think the -1 is unfair! of course it has a lot to do with PostGIS. I have an spatial database that i am trying to use from other machines using QGIS. (I think in this page I don't need to explain much more..)
I'll see that Mapperz..

Comment: It is not the same @Mapperz, because that question asks for allowing all incoming connections, and I want to accept not all but just the connections coming from certain PCs. My problem is with dynamic IP addresses..

Comment: without setting your PC's to static IP you will need to open all the possible IP's, We have done this in a corporate environment

Comment: Does the router assign in the 192 range, maybe just change your subnet to  192.168.1.0/24

Answer (score 1):

Your only option other than static IPs is to open it up to listen to any IPs:

```
host    all             all             all                       md5
```

Going this method I would recommend you change the connection to require SSL connections by replacing `host` with `hostssl` like this:

```
hostssl    all             all          all                     md5
```

Be warned, I have found a couple commercial products that will **not** connect to PostgreSQL using SSL Required.  MapBox Studio is one of such projects unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to access the database from any machine inside the local network is to set the address to the whole subnet range (as @LR1234567 said):

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             192.168.1.0/24          md5
```

or

```
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

as @RustProof said.

depending on the net restriction we need.