# Error connecting to PostgreSql 9.2 using Autocad Map 2011

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.0, autocad-map

I want to connect Postgresql 9.2 database (installed at localhost , port-5432) from AutoCad Map 2011 (installed in same PC). 
I have successfully copied all required dll files (total 13 nos.) from PostGIS bin folder to C:***\AutoCAD Map 3D 2011\FDO\bin & also edited the providers.xml at C:***\AutoCAD Map 3D 2011\FDO\bin with below mentioned snippet before the final

```
<FeatureProvider>
<Name>OSGeo.PostGIS.3.4</Name>
<DisplayName>Fournisseur OSGeo FDO pour PostGIS </DisplayName>
<Description>Accès en lecture/écriture à une banque de données de type PostGIS.</Description>
<IsManaged>False</IsManaged>
<Version>3.4.0.0</Version>
<FeatureDataObjectsVersion>3.4.0.0</FeatureDataObjectsVersion>
<LibraryPath>PostGISProvider.dll</LibraryPath>
</FeatureProvider>
```

List of dlls - comerr32.dll, gssapi32.dll, k5sprt32.dll, krb5_32.dll, libeay32.dll, libiconv-2.dll, libintl-8.dll, libpq.dll, msvcr90.dll, ssleay32.dll, PostGISMessage.dll, PostGISProvider.dll, PostGISOverrides.dll

But with all the above mentioned efforts & all connection credentials duly checked the connection is not possible.

[image: AutoCAD Map 2011 - PostgreSql9.2 Error]

Please advice

Comment: if you want to connect from Map 2011 it won't help to copy the files into Map 2010 folders. Rob

Comment: is postgres allowing localhost connections? see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/122696/modifying-pg-hba-conf-file-to-listen-local-tcp-ip-conection

Comment: Yes..postgres allowing db connections, i have checked that also